# Get minimum and maximum datetime for each row between a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm struggling with this! My data is like the table below except there would be more than one user. Note that it isn't just a start/end time, there are many dates in between.

```
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| Date                    | Name 2 | Access                    |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-29 14:50:03.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 1 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 08:42:33.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 2 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 08:42:58.000 | User1  | 1st Floor Door 1 (In)     |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 12:31:54.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 1 (Out) |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 13:05:43.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 1 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 13:11:32.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 3 (Out) |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 13:55:28.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 1 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-30 13:55:36.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 2 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-09-01 18:31:21.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 4 (Out) |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-10-01 08:31:21.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 1 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-10-01 08:31:41.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 2 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-10-01 17:31:49.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 4 (Out) |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-10-02 08:31:51.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 1 (In)  |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| 2014-10-02 18:41:49.000 | User1  | Ground Floor Door 3 (Out) |
+-------------------------+--------+---------------------------+
```

I need to obtain the minimum and maximum value for each day between a range of dates. If I could calculate how long the lunch period was (difference between the first and last swipes between 12pm-2pm) that would be great as well but not important until I can get the first part working.

I've tried various versions of the query below so far but had no joy. Can anyone help me please? I have no problem getting the min and max for a specific date, it's only when there is a range involved that it doesn't work.

```
select min(Date) as EntryTime, max(Date) as ExitTime
from table
where [Name 2] like '%User1%' and EventTime between '2014-09-30 12:00:00' and '2014-10-05 12:00:00'
group by cast(Date as datetime)
```

This doesn't give the desired result set. I want my query to return something like this for my table:

```
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------+
| EntryTime               | ExitTime                | Username | Date       |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------+
| 2014-09-30 08:42:33.000 | 2014-09-01 18:31:21.000 | User1    | 2014-09-01 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------+
| 2014-10-01 08:31:21.000 | 2014-10-01 17:31:49.000 | User1    | 2014-10-01 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------+
| 2014-10-02 08:31:51.000 | 2014-10-02 18:41:49.000 | User1    | 2014-10-02 |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: What is the output of this query and what is wrong with it?

Comment: My query gives me the same date twice for each row for the min/max columns

Comment: The attributes in your query and your sample data don't match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your cast, try `CAST AS DATE` :

```
select name_2,
       min(`date`) as EntryTime,
       max(`date`) as ExitTime,
       cast(`date` As Date) as YourDate
  from table
where UserName like '%User1%'
   and EventTime between '2014-09-30 12:00:00' and '2014-10-05 12:00:00'
 group by cast(`date` As Date), name_2
```

Comment: For some reason I can't cast as date in this database. "Type Date is not a defined system type." I got around it using CONVERT(varchar(11),Event) and your query worked! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

this will give you a list of users each with every day's min and max

```
select cast(Date as datetime) as Date,Name,min(Date) as EntryTime, max(Date) as ExitTime
from table
where Date between '2014-09-30 12:00:00' and '2014-10-05 12:00:00'
group by cast(Date as datetime),Name
```

you may need to cast Date field into Date type

Comment: Its not even close, he wants min and max for each day, not for each name.

Comment: This doesn't work because it only returns the minimum for the first date (2014-09-30) and the maximum for the last date (2014-10-05). It needs to get a minimum and maximum for EACH day that has entries in the database

Comment: @sagi - not far either

Comment: And now its just like my answer, you even copied the column name, are you serious ?

Comment: @sagi - take a look -its not even close ;)

Comment: Exactly the same, using the same column name as mine, only you excluded the filter on userName, which should be included!

Comment: you are correct. I did copy (my mistake. sorry) your field name instead of OP's. correcting

Comment: If you are so woried about the downvote I'll take it down, but don't copy next time, and read the question better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what you get

SELECT  MIN([Date]) AS 'EntryTime',
        MAX([Date]) AS 'ExitTime',
        NAME
FROM    Test
WHERE   CAST([Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN cast(getdate()-2 as date) and cast(getdate() as date)
AND     NAME ='user 1'
GROUP BY CAST([Date] AS DATE), NAME

Testing this on my own table it works correctly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ddyi.png)